# Why does the bluetooth le device name sometimes show up in advertisements and sometimes not?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I wrote a very simple Windows app that creates a BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher. When the OnAdvertisementReceived is called the code called BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync to retrieve the associated bluetooth le device object and I have noticed that the Name property is sometimes filled in correctly and sometimes empty. Does Windows maintain a ble device name cache?

Comment: Yes, Windows does. Once you start Watcher winows waits for device's name advertisement frame and caches it. However, to get the device's name it is better to parse advertisement instead of creating a device object.

Comment: The advertisement data sections never contain a section of type 0x08 (Shortened Local Name) or 0x09 (Complete Local Name) so I am wondering where Windows is capturing the BLE device namefrom.

Comment: It can reat it from GAP

Comment: I don't see anything in the Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile Namespace  that could return data that contains a device name. I also looked at the the GAP specification for hints and still no joy. What am I missing?

Comment: Device Information Service

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It turns out the name value I was looking for is located in the GenericAccess service.